# Use a project hosted on GitHub with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to compare 2 strings and see the similarity between 2 strings. I found this project in Github, https://github.com/aceakash/string-similarity and it looks exactly like what I need. However, I need it to work with my Google Sheets script. I've never used anything from Github before (beginner alert), would you be able to help point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: There is no support for "checking out" external resources for use in your Apps Script project. In git you would use a submodule or fork, but Apps Scripts' only versioned resource import is via Apps Script libraries - which are Apps Script projects. The closest thing you could do is to develop locally, with clasp as your deployment tool. This will allow you to use your preferred versioning software to maintain external resources and have them "imported" into your Apps Script project. Read the guide to using clasp for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the guide! I've checked out clasp and it looks pretty cool. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to utilise an externally hosted javascript library in a Google apps script function and it is described in the article [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/20380-load-external-javascript-with-eval).

It uses the javascript `eval()` function which is generally discouraged or even forbidden but you may be able to make a case for it if you are using `eval()` on a trusted resource and there is no way for arbitrary code to be injected.

The library you want to use however is not suitable as it is a server-side node.js module and uses `require` which is not supported by Google Apps Script. There are however a number of other client-side libraries that you could use.

The function below loads the [clj-fuzzy](http://yomguithereal.github.io/clj-fuzzy/javascript.html) javascript file from an external source - most javascript libraries are available on a CDN somewhere. The clj-fuzzy library seems to have the same sample - "healed" compared with "sealed" as the library you suggested.

```
function COMPARE_DISTANCE(s1, s2) {

  var url = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clj-fuzzy@0.4.1/src-js/clj-fuzzy.min.js";
  var javascript = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  eval(javascript);

  var distance = clj_fuzzy.metrics.dice(s1, s2);

  return distance;

}
```

You can call this from your sheet

```
=COMPARE_DISTANCE(A1, B1)
```

And it will return 0.8 for the test strings.

Note: this library has a comment saying that it is deprecated but if it does what you need it probably won't vanish.

It seems very wasteful that you have to download the external resource for each call of the function - there could be bad performance problems if you used it in a sheet with thousands of rows.

Honestly, you might be better downloading the file and adding it to your project directly.

Comment: i cant vote up but this is exactly what i was looking for! thank you. Though, I'm just curious how you got this URL, https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clj-fuzzy@0.4.1/src-js/clj-fuzzy.min.js?

Comment: I did a search for javascript library that has string similarity functionality and found clj-fuzzy. Then I searched for "clj-fuzzy cdn" and that is the first result.  Most open source javascript libraries are available on a cdn (content delivery network) somewhere.